# Failed to download file from S3 bucket. ( Langchain + s3 )

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, langchain

I'm coding a project use s3 to store file pdf, and use **langchain** to connect and load file.
This is my code:
`const loader = new S3Loader({ bucket: process.env.BUCKET, key: filekey, // example: test/e3959622-7fb1-44ab-a506.pdf s3Config: { accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY, region: "us-east-1" }, unstructuredAPIURL: "http://localhost:8000/general/v0/general", // confusing });`

when upload file to s3, everything is good. But, when I try to call my api to handle for feature, I get this error:
*Failed to download file test/e3959622-7fb1-44ab-a506.pdf from S3 bucket .*

Please, explain to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify Bucket Name: Ensure that the process.env.BUCKET variable
   contains the correct name of your S3 bucket. Double-check that the
   bucket exists and that you have provided the correct name.
2. Check File Key: Confirm that the filekey variable contains the
   correct file key, including the path within the bucket. In your
   example, the file key is test/e3959622-7fb1-44ab-a506.pdf. Ensure
   that the file is located at the specified path in your S3 bucket.
3. S3 Access Credentials: Check the values of process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY
   and process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY to ensure they contain valid AWS
   access key and secret access key credentials, respectively. Make
   sure these credentials have appropriate permissions to access the S3
   bucket and download files.
4. Verify AWS Region: Confirm that the region specified in region:
   "us-east-1" matches the region where your S3 bucket is located. If
   your bucket is in a different region, update the region value
   accordingly.
5. Verify Unstructured API URL: Ensure that the unstructuredAPIURL is
   set correctly and points to the valid endpoint for your API handling
   the file download. Double-check the URL, including the hostname and
   port number, to ensure it is accessible and configured correctly.
6. Check S3 Bucket Permissions: Verify that the IAM user or role
   associated with the access key and secret key has the necessary
   permissions to download objects from the S3 bucket. Ensure that the
   appropriate permissions are granted for the bucket and the specific
   file you are trying to download.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the aws cli tool, and run
`aws configure`.
I faced the same issue, but couldnt figure out why it was not taking my config provided in the s3Config object.
I got around it by setting my default aws varaibles using `aws configure`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong type definition for S3Config interface on S3Loader,
tempFix: create customS3Loader with the same code but using the correct types.

https://github.com/hwchase17/langchainjs/issues/1460

If you have the aws-cli installed and configured, the client use that config instead of the S3Config object.

Answer (score 0):

have you contacted

[1]: https://unstructured.io/ to get API url for unstructured API? , it seems  to me that you're trying to listen on a localhost